# How can I print out the value of an int in xcode debugger?

Tags: ios, uitableview, int, nsindexpath

I have a UItableView where the user is selecting the first row, my indexPath is showing ( 0 - 0) and I try to se my int to **indexPath.row**. However when I try to do this when I log it using **po myintname** it returns `<nil>` to the console.

This is what my code looks like.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    int tempIndexPathRow = indexPath.row;

    selectedItemIndexPathRow = tempIndexPathRow;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `po` expects an object (print object). If you need the value of a primitive such as an `int`, write only `p myintname` to the console.

Comment: whoops.. okay so it returned (int) $0 = 0 which I guess is what I am after. thanks.